# Use TBODY for every row in a TABLE? (and does it matter for semantics?)

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm reworking a table class in PHP. One of its functions is that one block of data can span multiple TRs. For this feature I'm now using TBODY tags to group these rows together.

However, this got me thinking about the TBODY semantic. I know the convention is that tables have one TBODY, and use one block of data per TR. But shouldn't every TR be contained in a TBODY then?

Answer (score 2):

> the convention is that tables have one TBODY, and use one set of data per TR.

That is not necessarily true. Each TR represents a row, and nothing more. If you have a group of rows that are related, it's alright to contain each group in its own TBODY. It's perfectly fine for a single table to have multiple table bodies; [the HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TBODY) demonstrates a table with two bodies or blocks of data:

```
<TABLE>
<THEAD>
     <TR> ...header information...
</THEAD>
<TFOOT>
     <TR> ...footer information...
</TFOOT>
<TBODY>
     <TR> ...first row of block one data...
     <TR> ...second row of block one data...
</TBODY>
<TBODY>
     <TR> ...first row of block two data...
     <TR> ...second row of block two data...
     <TR> ...third row of block two data...
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Does it matter for semantics? Maybe, maybe not. Personally, I'd go with adding the extra tags for kicks.

Comment: You restated what I said very well. :) Now for the question: if one block of data only spans one TR (which is far more common), shouldn't that single TR be grouped into a TBODY as well? Wouldn't it normally (one TBODY, many TRs) mean that all the data blocks in a table is one group? While actually, they're all separate data blocks..

Comment: Oh I kind of misread your question. Well, having a TBODY for each and every TR seems like clutter to me... I say in that case just do away with the TBODY tags altogether.

Answer (score 1):

HTML allows for multiple TBODY tags in one table (but only one THEAD and TFOOT). So while it may not be conventional (and waste some bytes), I don't see any good reason not to wrap each TR in a distinct TBODY if this fits your application.

Comment: I'm not wondering about its practical uses, but whether or not it is better form to do it this way. I doubt search engines really care, but maybe only because we've been doing it wrong all this time?